# Is there a way to easily condense the shared column(s) in an inner join into a single column(s) while still fetching all the information?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I know we can specify our data in the select, but These tables have a lot of columns, so I'm trying to see if there's a way to save some time!

So instead of the following, is there another way to merge the similar columns and return all data without the duplicate columns?

```
select 
  coalesce(a.item, b.item, c.item) as item,
  coalesce(a.thing, b.thing, c.thing) as thing,
  a.something, 
  b.somethingelse, 
  c.thirdthing
from a
inner join b on a.ID = b.ID
inner join c on a.ID = c.ID
```

Comment: In general, no.  You are doing it the right way.  But you should tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. This is the third* question of mine you've answered and I appreciate it!